# File upload with Remix.run: File object turns into a string in action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, form-data

I am working on a Remix application where users can upload files via a form. I have a handler function for the form submission that takes the form data, including a file attachment, and posts it to my action.

The issue is, when I receive the file in the action, it seems to be received as a string rather than a File object or a Blob. When I check if the incoming object is an instance of a File using value instanceof File, it returns false.

Heres my handle submit:

```
 const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
        const requiredFields = [
            "projectName",
            "blockchain",
            "supply",
            "mintPrice",
            "mintDate",
            "twitterLink",
            "emailContact",
            "description",
            "teamSummary",
            "teamMembers",
            "references",
            "documents",
            "artwork",
            "marketing",
            "allowlist",
            "investment",
        ];
    const newErrors = {...initialErrors};
    let $form = event.currentTarget;
    let formData = new FormData($form);

    requiredFields.forEach(field => {
        if (!projectForm[field as keyof ProjectFormState]) {
            newErrors[field] = true;
        }
    });

    if (Object.values(newErrors).some(value => value)) {
        setErrors(newErrors);
        return;
    }

    console.log('projectForm', projectForm);

    Object.entries(projectForm).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        console.log('file type in submit', value instanceof File)
        if (value instanceof File) {
            console.log('file value', value)
            formData.append(key, value, value.name);
        } else {
            formData.set(key, value);
        }
    });

    submit(formData, {
        method: $form.getAttribute("method") as HTMLFormMethod ?? $form.method,
        action: $form.getAttribute("action") ?? $form.action,
    });
};
```

Here the file value log is called, however in my action:

```
export const action = async ({request}: ActionArgs) => {
const formData = await request.formData();
const project: ProjectFormFields = {} as ProjectFormFields;

await Promise.all(Array.from(formData.entries()).map(async ([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value); // Log the value of 'value'
    console.log(value instanceof File); // Check whether 'value' is a File instance
    if (value instanceof File) {
        const arrayBuffer = await value.arrayBuffer();
        project[key] = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
    } else {
        project[key] = value;
    }
}));

console.log(project)

try {
    const response = await putProjectForm(project);
    const {status} = response;
    console.log('Form submission response', status);

    return redirect("/", {
        headers: {
            "Set-Cookie": `message=Your form was submitted successfully; Path=/;`,
        },
    });

} catch(error) {
    console.error('There was an error with the form submission', error);
}

return null;
```

}

The `console.log(value instanceof File);` returns false. Im not sure if its how im appending the file onto the formdata. But any help would be massive! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use "multer" package for storing the file in one of your folders and then just save the url in your database.

```html
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./public/images/");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
  },
});
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
  file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
  file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
    ? cb(null, true)
    : cb(null, false);
};
app.use(multer({ storage, fileFilter }).single("image"));
```

you can use this express app.use() in server.js
use enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.